# Authorization in SOAP using PHP for sletat.ru

Tags: php, .net, soap, authorization

I have an official doc example of using soap protocol requiring authorisation on .Net
How could I do the same on PHP?

```
using System;
using WcfClient.Gate;
namespace WcfClient
{
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
// создаём экземпляр обёртки для работы с поисковым сервисом
using (var gate = new Soap11GateClient())
{
// указываем данные для авторизации на сервисе
var authInfo = new AuthData() { Login = "********", Password = "********" };
// далее нам доступен вызов любых методов сервиса
var cities = gate.GetDepartCities(authInfo);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Start here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Have read already, tried this one:
$wsdl_url = 'http://module.sletat.ru/XmlGate.svc?wsdl';
try {                                            
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array('login' => "griffin",
              'password'       => "password"));
} catch (Exception $e) {                           
        printf("Error:sendSms: %s\n",$e->__toString());
        return false;                              
}

var_dump($client->GetDepartCities()); 
it makes errorUncaught SoapFault exception: [a: InternalServiceFault] Data for authorization title AuthData not provided

Comment: How can I pass Authorization data as the first parameter to all methods of the service?

Answer (score 0):

I found authorization solution from sletat.ru for php. The matter was in SoapHeader format:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://module.sletat.ru/XmlGate.svc?wsdl');

$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader("urn:SletatRu:DataTypes:AuthData:v1", "AuthInfo", array(
        "Login" => '********',
        'Password'=> '********',
    )));
```